# Getting Pure Data to work on Raspbian Jessie (giving Pure Data permission to access device?)

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, permissions, puredata

I’m new to Raspberry Pi and am trying to run Pure Data on it to control a teensy 3.2 using Open Sound Control which in turn controls some stepper motors for a pump just like here https://github.com/DropletKitchen/pumpsn17 (using the teensy code and Pd files provided at the end of the page). I’ve finally managed to install Pd-extended on my Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian Jessie). But I don’t think Pd is able to use the USB to communicate with the teensy, since if I try to run the Pd file, Pd gives me the error “could not open device /dev/ttyS0: failure(13): Permission denied. Could someone help me please to get Pd communicating with OSC through my USB?

Also when I open Pd I get this message

```
/dev/dsp (read/write): No such file or directory
```

(now will try write-only…)

```
/dev/dsp (writeonly): No such file or directory
/dev/dsp (read only): No such file or directory
```

and

```
Audio I/O stuck... closing audio
```

Do I need to do some further configuration to get Pure Data running properly?

Like I mentioned I am very new to using the Raspberry Pi so any help would be appreciated and please do explain anything as if I were an idiot. That would really help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/ttyS0` is the UART connected to GPIO 14/15.

If you have a serial (USB) dongle attached it will be named something like `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: `/dev/ttyS0` is the **default** serial for Pi3 BUT users should be encouraged to use `dev/serial0` which is the accessible serial on all models, including the Pi3, even if BT is swapped. Either way it is disabled by default.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. So I am trying to communicate through the wrong output. Is this something I can change on the Raspberry Pi, to force it to use the USB ports? or is this something I need to change on the PD code. I'm pretty new to all this and the PD code was written by someone else, who apparently got it working on the raspberry pi. I know very little about how to use PD, but would love to get this working, the closest thing I can see to a reference to where to output to is "devicename /dev/tty.usbmodem12341, pollintervall 1"

Comment: @Paul If you are connecting via a USB dongle you must tell PD to use that (e.g. try `/dev/ttyUSB0`.  I know nothing about PD, you will have to find where it holds its configuration data.

Comment: the user interface on the PD file, should allow me to chose my output port (from 0-4). 0 and 1 seem to open serial line device dev/ttyAMA0  or 1. whilst 2 gives an error, permission denied (this is when it tries to use dev/ttyS0) whilst 3 and 4 report that they do not exist (max == 2)

Comment: Thank you Joan. I will try to learn a bit more about PD and change the code to use /dev/ttyUSB0. I presume since I have 4 USB ports on the Raspberry pi, that these would be /dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyUSB1, /dev/ttyUSB2 and /dev/ttyUSB3?

Comment: @Paul Pretty much, although I think it allocates by order of insertion rather than by port.

Comment: @joan thanks for your help and input, it's really appreciated. However I am still having no luck, after a number of different attempts I can’t get through to the teensy. A few others have suggested that I should find the teensy on dev/ttyACM0. I’ve also tried this, but to no avail. In the Pure Data program when I search for devices I can only find dev/ttyACM0 and dev/ttyS0. I no longer get permission errors for either of these, which is nice.

Comment: But I do still get other errors. If I open PD L2Ork on the Raspberry pi I initially get an error saying “audio I/0 error…”. If I open the PD extended program instead, I used to get the same error but then since typing:

Comment: sudo apt install alsa-oss
sudo modprobe snd-pcm-oss

Comment: in the command to create a /dev/dsp device as per the advice of another raspberry pi user.
 But if I open the Pure Data files that I need, in either of the Pd program versions I get: 
UnpackOSC
… couldn’t create
routeOSC /derection
… couldn’t create 
And then a bunch of other could not create warnings for all the OSC parameters.  It seems like the OSC elements are not working. The PD L2Ork also identifies that the helper file o.io.slipserial.pd 5 0 4 0 (bng->loadbang) connection failed

Comment: Suggesting the communication between the “loadbang” control in the PD file and the helper file. I’m starting to think this may be a problem with the PD code rather than so much a Raspberry pi related one, although I am assured the PD files work. I’m trying to get in touch with the creators (to no avail) and also some help from PD users. But if anyone here has any helpful suggestions I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone’s help here. It’s great how much help you can get from others on this forum. I after a bit of a learning curve I ended up solving this problem with help from David “whale-av” at PDpatchrepro forum: https://forum.pdpatchrepo.info/topic/11149/getting-pure-data-to-work-on-raspbian-jessie-giving-pure-data-permission-to-access-device

Comment: It turned out the files provided for the open sound control on Pure data were missing one small piece of code. This is because the object [import mrpeach] needs to be referenced in all the PD files that are provided to enable OSC to communicate with the Teensy. To solve this I added an object to the file Flexible3or4PumpsGOP and inserted the command “[import mrpeach]”, I also did this to the front end file to make sure, although I’m not sure it is necessary. It should already be referenced in o.io.slipserial.pd. Once this is done it should work.

Comment: The raspberry pi now talks to the teensy via ttyACM0. So glad to get this working, and thanks for the help along the way.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.